# Angular - Conflict Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename

Tags: angular

I updated my Angular from 10 to 14 and now when I try to run my application I get this error

Compiled with problems:

> ERROR
>
> Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename
> data-table.svg

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

cheers

Zolf

Comment: Does the issue persists if you for example rename the file to data-table1.svg? Sometimes this error come on update Angular like you do.

Comment: Do I change the file name as I showed in the screenshot

Comment: Yes. or delete the file and add it again. Does this help?